# check if the value of a field changed in a before_update filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a database field where I want to store my password. In a before_create filter in my model I call a encryption function and save from clear text to encrypted text.

I want now to use the before_update also for encryption, but only if the value has changed. How can I write a condition for checking if a field value has changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you usually do not store the password in the model using a field which you would expose to the form, it should be sufficient to only update it `unless password.blank?` and have the real password in a field "hashed_password" which you won't expose to the form.

Thanks to Ben (see below) for pointing out to additionally protect your encrypted password with `attr_protected` so it cannot be directly accessed/updated from the form. +1

Comment: @xaver Be sure to make the hashed attribute field protected so it is not writeable by mass update actions through a form.

Comment: You can use attr_protected to help you with with hurikhan77 described.

Answer (score 27):

If the field is called name then

```
object.name_changed?
```

will return true.

Comment: Won't this always return true? Rails will be comparing the updated plaintext password with the encrypted existing password in the database and they'll always be different (I think).

Comment: @Farrel  I use the _changed? all the time and it is perfect.  Thanks for giving he answer.  I have a model which is basically a today and it belongs_to a requestor and an assignee.  I was wondering if there is a way to do a similar thing like _changed to the assignee?

Comment: You can also use: `object.changed` to get an Array with all changed fields